# if $A=_{c}B$, then $B=_{c}A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any sets A and B, $\:A=_{c}A, if\:A=_{c}B,\:then\:B=_{c}A$.  [Equinumerous]

This is the proposition from Yannis's set theory, and it is seems trivial, but I have no idea how to prove it. My intuition comes with injectivity from $A\:to\:B$  must have a left inverse, but it does not help.

Appreciate any comments and helps

Comment: Did you try writing down *everything* that this proposition gives you? (Perhaps reading [this](http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/) can help.)

Comment: re-edit one more condition, $A=_{c} A$, it seems trivial to this question

Comment: Could you include a description of what $=_c$ means?

Comment: @fleablood equinumerous

Comment: And what  does "equinumerous" mean.  That isn't a standard term.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:A\to B$ is a bijection then it has a unique inverse function $f^{-1}:B\to A$ which is characterized by $f\circ f^{-1}=\mathsf{id}_B$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=\mathsf{id}_A$, and is on its turn also a bijection.

So *existence* of a bijection $A\to B$ implies *existence* of a bijection $B\to A$.

Comment: definition of quinumerous from yannis's note only mentioned injective, I believe after proved this proposition, it's bijective. Would you please go with injective only. Thank you

Comment: But the existence of an injective function $f:A\to B$ is not enough for equal cardinalities (e.g. let $A$ be a singleton. Then every $f:A\to B$ is injective for every $B$). If there is an injective function $f:A\to B$ you can at most conclude that the cardinality of $A$ does not exceed the cardinality of $B$.

Comment: I put another condition which I thougth is trivial, $A=_{c}A$ is this gonna help?

Comment: you are right, I miss read the sign notation.

Comment: @LawrenceGuo I just looked up [Notes on Set Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZYFCAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=equinumerous&f=false)
by Yiannis Moschovakis, I assume that is what you mean. The definition he gives in words for equinumerous is unfortunately a little vague - "one-to-one correspondence" - but from the symbols it's clear that he means a *bijective* mapping (compare to the bijection arrow symbol from the definition of bijection.)

Comment: @JairTaylor that's right

Comment: That link *gives* a proof!  It's proposition 2.2   Anyway Jair Taylor and drhap are absolutely correct that this relies on *bi*jection, and not merely injection.  Injection alone is not enough as drhabs comment points out.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Jazeker, dat was een volle neef van mij. Ik moet erbij zeggen dat ik eigenlijk nooit contact met hem heb gehad hoor. Maar de uitdrukking "ren je rot" zit diep bij me ingeworteld.